# Reload a local script from a URL available source code?

Tags: scripting, here-document, url

I have a long script (>500 rows) I load in each bootstrapping of a webpage, from a local file. The source code of this script is often updated and presented under a certain URL so that all users could update their local files containing it (because it's that heavy many prefer loading it locally).

Not updating this script frequently expose my website for security breaches, but instead of copying and pasting the data each time a new to update, I want to reload it into my local automatically with a Cron task (say `0 0 1 * 0`).

Is there a way in Unix, to copy and paste all data from a URL accessible script into a local script file?

I guess this will include a rewrite like `<< EOF > ... EOF` But this time, not from my own local standard input in Bash prompt, but rather a remote file.

Comment: Install `curl` if you don't have it. Write a wrapper which downloads the script if needed and then `exec`s it.

Comment: What kind of wrapper you mean to? You are welcome to publish an answer with example. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 possible ways to do this:

### Way 1 - Use curl in a cron job:

Use `curl` (install it if it isn't already installed). `curl` downloads files using any of the usual protocol -- HTTP, HTTPS, FTP. You could use `curl` in a cron job to download a fresh copy of the script periodically. Use `man curl` for invocation details.

```
curl -o /path/to/script http://www.example.com/script
```

You may want to download the script under a name different than the script which is executed in production, and when the download succeeds `mv` it over the production script; this is to avoid any problem in case the script is called in mid-download.

### Way 2 - Use a Wrapper script:

Write a wrapper which downloads the script if needed, and then `exec`s or calls it (depending on the scripting language). The example is written is Bash so that the logic is easily comprehensible; for other scripting languages you will have to adapt. For example, suppose the local script is named `real-script` and the URL is `http://www.example.com/real-script`. The wrapper could be `wrapper-script`:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -f /path/to/real-script ] ; then
# Local copy exists, download only if remote file is newer
  curl -z /path/to/real-script -o /path/to/real-script http://www.example.com/real-script
else
# Local copy does not exist, always download
  curl -o /path/to/real-script http://www.example.com/real-script
fi
chmod 755 /path/to/real-script
exec /path/to/real-script "$@"
```

Call this wrapper script as if it was the real script; the wrapper will download the real script if there is no local copy or if the local copy is older than the remote file; then it will execute the guaranteed fresh copy passing any arguments.

You may also want to avoid looking for a newer version if the existing local copy is not more than 5 minutes old, or whatever time interval you allow.

Note that when using this method in production, some error checking will probably be needed.

Comment: As I said under point 1, just use `curl`: `curl -o /path/to/script http://www.example.com/script`. [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) is available for all kinds on Linux, and for Windows. Read the `curl` manual page, it's not long or complicated.

Comment: Surly, it's long or complicated, I thought your explanation dealt only with a 3-steps solution instead of 2 steps (I will add his as side note). I suggest comment deletion for minimal answer.